# Android animations not smooth on BackgroundImage

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator, animatorset

I created simple app with some animations in android. In my layout I have an ImageView with a sourceImage and a button on it. When I click the button, I want it move and resize in same time.
I used ObjectAnimator and ValueAnimator for create animations and play them together with animatorSet. My problem is that my button not move smoothly.
I checked several animation library like Transitions Everywhere and APIDemos. In these libraries when I set ImageBackground the view can't move smoothly 
and all of them have my problem.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

my layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start" />
//  ....................
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my animations code:

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ButtonAnimation();
     }
 });

private void ButtonAnimation() {
    Animator moveButtonAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn_start, "translationY", 0, 200)
            .setDuration(500);
    final ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(width_btn_start, width_btn_start * 2.0f);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            btn_start.getLayoutParams().width = value.intValue();
            btn_start.requestLayout();
        }
    });

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.playTogether(moveButtonAnimY, valueAnimator);
    animatorSet.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia:

> Animation is the process of making the illusion of motion and change by means of the rapid display of a sequence of static images that minimally differ from each other.

Therefore, animation is a pretty heavy task for the device to process, and the smoothness as you referred, depends upon the device configuration.

So, First check if the device have enough power to carry out that animation smoothly.

Secondly, Your code initializes animation every time the button is clicked, Instead you should initialize animation once, and use the instances of them every time you need to start the animation.

A better version of your code would be :

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ButtonAnimation();
    }
});
Animator moveButtonAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn_start,"translationY", 0, 200).setDuration(500);
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(width_btn_start, width_btn_start * 2.0f);
valueAnimator.setDuration(500);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        btn_start.getLayoutParams().width = value.intValue();
        btn_start.requestLayout();
    }
});
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playTogether(moveButtonAnimY, valueAnimator);

private void ButtonAnimation() {
    animatorSet.start();
}
```

Comment: alok, I test your code in my LG g3 but doesn't see any change in animations speed !